# What does ( WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN ) do?

Tags: visual-studio, api, vb6

i was studying the example of how to make round-shape form in Visual Basic 6, and i stopped at the code :
**`Public Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1`**
I only know that this is a message to the windows passed as Const ...

What i want to know is :

- what is &HA1 ?
- what does Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN do ? what message does it send to Windows ?
- anything else about it .

Please, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are working with messages that Windows sends to a window to tell your code that something interesting happened.  You'll find this constant used in the WndProc() method of a form, the method that runs when Windows sends a message.

The WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message is one of those messages.  WM = Window Message.  NC = Non Client, the part of the window that's not the client area, the borders and the title bar.  L = Left button, you can figure out BUTTONDOWN.

These messages are declared in a Windows SDK file.  You'll have it on your machine, the VS2008 version of that file is located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Include\WinUser.h.  Open it with a text editor or VS to see what's inside.  Search for the message identifier to find this line:

```
 #define WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN                0x00A1
```

The Windows SDK was written to work with C programs.  #define is equivalent to Const in VB.NET.  The `0x` prefix means 'hexadecimal' in the C language, just like &H does in VB.NET.  The Windows calculator is helpful to convert hexadecimal values to decimal and back, use View + Programmer.  You'll see the reason that &H is used in a VB.NET program, these constants started out in hexadecimal in the core declaration.  But `Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 161` will work just as well (10 x 16 + 1).

So within WndProc() you'd use a Select Case or If statement to detect the message.  And you can do something special when the user clicks the left mouse button on the window title bar.  If you ignore it then `MyBase.WndProc(m)` runs and the normal thing happens: Windows starts a modal loop that lets the user move the window.  It is actually *very* rare that you want to stop or alter that behavior, users are pretty fond of that default behavior since *all* windows in Windows behave that way.  The only message whose behavior you'd typically want to customize is WM_NCHITTEST.  Very useful to give a borderless window border-like behavior.  But that's another story.

Answer (score 3):

- That's a hexadecimal integer literal
- It declares a constant; it doesn't actually do anything.
  The [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is posted when the user presses the left mouse button while the cursor is within the nonclient area of a window. This message is posted to the window that contains the cursor

Answer (score 1):

- `&HA1` means the [hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number A1, i.e., 161 (though you'll usually see Windows message constants represented in hex). More commonly you'll see this as `0xA1` (or `0x00A1`) since that's how the hex number would be represented in C or C++ (the Windows API was originally written for C).
- You won't be sending `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` to Windows; it's the other way around. Windows will be sending *you* `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`.

If you want to know what `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` is for, [the documentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=wm_nclbuttondown) is just a Web-search away.

Comment: To be fair, it is also possible to send the WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN message programatically ;)

Comment: @JoshSanders, sure, although hopefully not in production code.

Comment: Well, you would be surprised. Windows does some nasty things inside of the DefWindowProc while handling some messages. For the case of handling WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, on non-aero enabled machines, Windows will force a repaint of the default system frame for the non-client areas of a custom-painted frame.

What does this mean? It means that if your're running windows XP and you don't handle the message yourself, your nice custom painted title bar will suddenly turn into a Windows system default title bar. Windows has this problem with several messages unfortunately, WM_SETICON, WM_SETCURSOR, etc

Comment: My point is though, sometimes you might need to send the message yourself to invoke some sort of custom handler you may have. A good example of this would be in CEF's hwnd_message_handler.cc where they send explicit WM_SYSMCOMMAND messages to prevent the exact Windows bugs I mentioned above :)

Comment: @JoshSanders: You would still *hopefully* never have to send *this particular* message, though.