# Monitor Scaling Issue for Moveable Access Form using MoveWindow win32 API

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, winapi, user32

I am trying to build a fully custom window frame from an Access popup form. Therefore, I had to disable the border style property from the form property sheet and replace it with 4 shapes that I use as my top, left, right and bottom borders. By doing so I lost the ability to drag/move the form while holding my mouse. As a result, had to use the mouse down/up/move functions on the top shape to make it draggable/moveable.

Initially used the build in function “Form.Move”, but soon realized that it will be a problem for a multi-monitor setup. Therefore, had to switch and use the win32 api to benefit from the “MoveWindow” function, as well as the “GetPhysicalCursorPos” function.

With the provided code bellow if my three monitors are scaled at the same percentage from the Windows Settings > System > Display option regardless of the screens resolution the form is moving flawlessly. However, as my third monitor is scaled at 300% compared to my other two at 150% once the form is on the 300% scaled monitor it starts to behave rather strangely.  Further investigation from my Debug Print of the mouse x and y coordinates as well as top left x y coordinates of my form showed a huge jumps between the x,y positions. Therefore, making the form jump from one place of the screen to another instead of transitioning smoothly when I slide my mouse.

I would be grateful if someone could provide me with any hints on how I can tackle this scaling issue to prevent this from happening. Thanks in advance!

Debug Output:

```
975 and 1018 .................. 678 and 1463
1463 and 678 .................. 1018 and 975
975 and 1018 .................. 678 and 1463
1463 and 678 .................. 1018 and 975
975 and 1018 .................. 678 and 1463
1463 and 678 .................. 1018 and 975
975 and 1018 .................. 678 and 1463
```

Form code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim moveFormStatus As Boolean

Private Sub rctgl_formTopBorder_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    moveFormStatus = True
End Sub

Private Sub rctgl_formTopBorder_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    If moveFormStatus = True Then
        Dim myrect As RECT
        Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
        GetWindowRect Me.hwnd, myrect
        GetPhysicalCursorPos llCoord
        MoveWindow Me.hwnd, llCoord.Xcoord, llCoord.Ycoord, myrect.right - myrect.left, myrect.bottom - myrect.top, True
        
        Debug.Print myrect.top & " and " & llCoord.Xcoord & " .................. " & myrect.left & " and " & llCoord.Ycoord
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rctgl_formTopBorder_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    moveFormStatus = False
End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Declare PtrSafe Function MoveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal bRepaint As Boolean) As Boolean
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetPhysicalCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Public Type POINTAPI
   Xcoord As Long
   Ycoord As Long
End Type

Public Type RECT
    left As Long
    top As Long
    right As Long
    bottom As Long
End Type
```

Comment: Subclass the window and handle the [`WM_NCHITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-nchittest) message as appropriate. When you return `HTCAPTION` the system handles the window movement for you.

Comment: I am not sure if I have done it right, but I followed your advice and ended up using two new user32 functions (`SendMessage` and `ReleaseCapture`). In addition, added two constants (`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1` and `HTCAPTION = 2`. Last I created a public function called `MvFrmWin` and inside added two functions (`ReleaseCapture`, and after that `SendMessage .hwnd, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HTCAPTION, 0`). Next, I created a `MouseDown` event on the top shape in my form and only called the above function `MvFrmWin Me` inside the event.

Comment: In the end I was able to move the form using this method. However, once the mouse goes to my third monitor in the area where it started jumping with my above-mentioned code, the form simply doesn’t want to move anymore. If I bring the mouse back to the area where it was working with the above-mentioned code it behaves normal again. In conclusion with this method the form jumping is prevented, but still, you cannot move the window to the “bad” area of my 300% scaled monitor.  Any input from your side will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Scrap all the code you have and *only* handle the `WM_NCHITTEST` message. As soon as you return `HTCAPTION` the system will take it from there and automagically move your window. No mouse capturing is required, and the window will stick to the mouse pointer (as opposed to lag behind as it does with your current implementation).

Comment: @IInspectable: Interesting. Never heard of `WM_NCHITTEST`. Would you be able to write (as an answer) the basic code needed?

Comment: [Hit testing is used for more than just dragging](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110218-00/?p=11453). In any case, you dont need to handle WM_NCHITTEST at all. You can alternatively just send the window a `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)` message when the mouse is held down on your window. That simulates when the user holds the mouse down on the titlebar. The window will drag normally until you release the mouse. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976610/

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for the follow up comment. This is far away from my comfortable zone, I tried to adapt my code based on the tips you gave me but I was not fully sure if I did it correctly. As a result, ended replacing the `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` with `WM_NCHITTEST` and keeping the rest of the `SendMessage` as it was before. Furthermore, I defined a global constant `WM_NCHITTEST = &H84`. I didn’t get an error, but the form was no longer moveable. As a result to fix it I saw that in the docs it was mentioned `DefWindowProc` so I replaced the `SendMessage` with that but it didn’t work either.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the provided article. It was really interesting to read as this is something very new to me. Furthermore, I tried to integrate the `delphi` solution that you linked to my form and use the `WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_DRAGMOVE)`. In addition, I noticed that `Perform` in `delphi` seems rather similar to `SendMessage`. As a result, I ended up with the following code `SendMessage Me.hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_DRAGMOVE, 0` with the two being defined as `WM_SYSCOMMAND = &H112` and `SC_DRAGMOVE = &H2`. However, this solution despite not giving an error no longer moves the form.

Comment: It is interesting that the solution by @AccessWorker doesn't work for you. Could you perhaps share a small gif of the behavior so I can replicate it on my end? The solution proposed by IInspectable is very hard to implement in VBA (calbacks are a pain) but a fun exercise so I might give that a shot. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74246448/7296893 for an example of window subclassing and hooking, that might tackle some of your issues.

Comment: I don't have an Access license, so cannot work towards a solution. Unless it's using the same `Form` implementation as Excel, PowerPoint, or Word. Could you use a tool like [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment) and report the window class of your form?

Comment: @ErikA The more I am looking into it, the weirder it becomes. AccessWorker's feedback was quite useful, as I expanded my field of testing once I realized that the issue cannot be replicated. As a result, I started testing the scaling settings on my computer/screens even more. My setup involves 2 monitors (27inch | 150% both scaled up) and 1 TV (43 inch | 300% scaled up) all of the three devices being 4K.

Comment: When I increased the scale of my second monitor compared to my first (default) monitor the issue was not present. However, if my TV is scaled more than my first (default) monitor then there is that “bad” section of the screen where the form no longer can be moved. The higher the difference in scale between my first (default) monitor and the TV the larger this “bad” zone becomes. Last but not least, I also found that as long as the TV is scaled below or equal to the first (default) monitor this issue is no longer present. Here is a [GIF](https://ibb.co/y85jNRq) showing the issue on my TV.

Comment: Furthermore, I enabled the `border style` property to `thin` in the form properties (just to test), which gives the popup window a default title bar and with this enabled this issue is no longer there no matter of the scale between all three monitors. The only difference being that it seems the popup is being scaled up once it goes over to the TV screen compared to my approach where the form keeps the same size as it was from the first (default) monitor.

Comment: @IInspectable I will give it a try, but I will need some time to learn how exactly to use this tool and will report back.

Comment: @IInspectable Access forms are unfortunately very different from the UserForms present in all Office programs. You really need Access if you're going to test it.

Comment: This is starting to sound like intended system behavior. When you apply different scaling across displays with the same physical pixel size, the resulting *logical* pixel area becomes non-rectangular (the *Rearrange your displays* UI shows the true shape). This introduces corners, and you can no longer cross from one display into the other across the entire height. @ErikA I did not expect that. Does Access repurpose "standard" Windows Forms or yet another framework?

Comment: @IInspectable Unfortunately, yet another framework, Access forms are something unique as far as I know. You can use UserForms in Access as well and mix UserForms/Access Forms, but that's highly unusual.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way using winApi.

Put this in a global module.

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseCapture Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = &HA1
Private Const HT_CAPTION = 2

Public Function DragMe(handle As Long)
    On Error Resume Next
    ReleaseCapture
    SendMessage handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN , HT_CAPTION , 0
End Function
```

and then any form you want to move.

```
Private Sub {control_you_enabling_drag}_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    'Move this form
    DragMe Me.Hwnd
End Sub
```

This will move your form while mouse is pressed using the OS.
[WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781862/what-does-wm-nclbuttondown-do)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the same result to my poor attempt to recreate what @iinspectable has suggested. Where the form will move, but once it's on the 300% scaled monitor it will not move until the mouse is back in the "good" region of that monitor.

Comment: My monitor doesn't allow 300%. i've changed to 175% and it worked flawlessly. Not sure if you have any other code in play. @GeorgeSmith

Comment: Thanks for trying to replicate the issue. Your feedback was useful for further testing on my side. In order to avoid double posting I went a little bit on my findings in the thread going above.